# DELETE WITH SELECT (ERROR 1093)

Tags: mysql

I need to delete the results in this query:

```
SELECT a.cad_id
FROM `Cad` a
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT b.cad_id
FROM `rel` b
WHERE a.cad_id = b.rel
)
```

I try:

```
DELETE FROM `Cad` WHERE cad_id = (
SELECT a.cad_id
FROM `Cad` a
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT b.cad_id
FROM `rel` b
WHERE a.cad_id = b.rel
)
)
```

## 1093 - You can't specify target table 'Cad' for update in FROM clause

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select your inner query data in temporary table.

```
DELETE FROM `cad` 
WHERE  cad_id IN (SELECT * 
                 FROM  (SELECT a.cad_id 
                        FROM   `cad` a 
                        WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT b.cad_id 
                                           FROM   `rel` b 
                                           WHERE  a.cad_id = b.rel)) AS 
                       tempTable)
```

Comment: I get this error: #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: You used wrong `Where` condition its `DELETE FROM cad WHERE  cad_id = `. Use `IN` instead of `=`